# prefixing all files in multiple folders

Tags: windows, powershell, shell

I have several folder (35 to be exact), each folder contains 10-12 sub-folders and each sub folder about 20 files.

I want to prefix each file with the name of the sub-folder but the only command I found is for renaming only one folder at a time :

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " - " + $_.Name}
```

Is there a way to loop through all the folder ? (I'm not used to Powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-Recurse` switch to get items from subfolders too. Additionally you can also use the `-File` switch to return files only:

```
(dir -File -Recurse) | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " - " + $_.Name}
```

Note: As @postanote pointed out, it's always recommendable to test destructive commands first using the [-WhatIf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1#whatif) switch.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked but for some reason for the first folder's file got renamed several times (it's easy to fix but I'm curious why it happened ?)

Comment: @MohamedBOUAKKAZ Can you try if the updated command works better? The parantheses should make the command collect all files first, and rename after.

Comment: Never used destructive commands (Create, Update, Delete. Move), without testing them first. This is why the -WhatIf switch exists. It allows you to validate results before a real run. Protecting your system and your files is paramount, especially if you do not have a backup.

Comment: @postanote That is a valid point. I included a little hint in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, and it is detailed in the PowerShell Help files. That is what the -recurse parameter is for.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters.Keys|clip
# Results
<#
Path
LiteralPath
Filter
Include
Exclude
Recurse
Depth
Force
Name
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
UseTransaction
Attributes
Directory
File
Hidden
ReadOnly
System
#>

Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Examples
# Results
<#
Get-ChildItem
Get-Childitem -System -File -Recurse
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory,!Directory+Hidden
dir -att !d,!d+h
dir -ad
Get-ChildItem -File -Attributes !ReadOnly -path C:\ps-test
get-childitem . -include *.txt -recurse -force
get-childitem c:\windows\logs\* -include *.txt -exclude A*
get-childitem -name

#>
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Online


(Get-Command -NameR ename-Item).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Rename-Item).Parameters.Keys|clip
# Results
<#
Path
LiteralPath
NewName
Force
PassThru
Credential
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
WhatIf
Confirm
UseTransaction
#>

Get-help -Name Rename-Item -Examples
# Results
<#
Rename-Item -Path "c:\logfiles\daily_file.txt" -NewName "monday_file.txt"
Rename-Item -Path "project.txt" -NewName "d:\archive\old-project.txt"
Move-Item -Path "project.txt" -Destination "d:\archive\old-project.txt"
Rename-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\MyCompany\Advertising" -NewName "Marketing"
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -Replace '\.txt','.log' }
#>
Get-help -Name Rename-Item -Full
Get-help -Name Rename-Item -Online
```

Yet what you are doing in your code, is renaming the directory only, not the files in that directory or sub-directories. You have also not specified and start directory, so it will take action on whatever directory you are currently in vs the one you may want.

You need to loop all directors and loop all the files in those directories, to rename the files in that passed in the directory.

**Update as per my '-WhatIf' comment**

Just another way of doing what 'marzse' gave you, just with notification of what's being processed, and a check. Remove the -Whatif, if things look good, and run it again. Never ruin anyone's code if you are ae not absolutely sure what it is doing, or you are willing to accept the consequences of doing so.

```
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Directory | 
ForEach-Object {
    "`n *** Working on resource named: $($PSItem.BaseName) *** `n"
    $DirName = $($PSItem.BaseName)

    Get-ChildItem -Path $DirName -File | 
    ForEach{
        $PSItem.FullName | 
        Rename-Item -NewName "$($DirName)_$($PSItem)" -WhatIf
    } 
}
# Results test the rename process 
<#
*** Working on resource named: AddressFiles *** 

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp1\AddressFiles\(MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.pdf Destination: D:\temp1\AddressFiles\AddressFiles_(MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp1\AddressFiles\File1.txt Destination: D:\temp1\AddressFiles\AddressFiles_File1.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp1\AddressFiles\File2.txt Destination: D:\temp1\AddressFiles\AddressFiles_File2.txt".

 *** Working on resource named: ChildFolder *** 

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp1\ChildFolder\5 Free Software You'll Wish You Knew Earlier! 2019 - YouTube.url Destination: D:\temp1\ChildFolder\ChildFolder_5 Free Software You'll Wish You Knew Earlier! 2019 - YouTube.url".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp1\ChildFolder\awél.txt Destination: D:\temp1\ChildFolder\ChildFolder_awél.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp1\ChildFolder\hello.bat Destination: D:\temp1\ChildFolder\ChildFolder_hello.bat".
....

 *** Working on resource named: dest *** 

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp1\dest\mytest - 2019.txt Destination: D:\temp1\dest\dest_mytest - 2019.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp1\dest\mytest.txt Destination: D:\temp1\dest\dest_mytest.txt".
#>
```

Never rush into code or do all things at once. step in to in one step at a time to make sure you are getting what you'd expect at each step.

To get to the above, this is what I mean. Logical full step-thru, then once you understand you can optimize to what marsze shows.

```
Push-Location -Path 'D:\Temp1'
Get-Location
# Results
<#
Path    
----    
D:\temp1
#>

Get-ChildItem 
# Results all file in the root
<#
    Directory: D:\temp1


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                       
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                       
d-----         01-Nov-20     23:43                AddressFiles                                                                                               
d-----         01-Nov-20     23:43                BonoboGitServer                                                                                            
d-----         01-Nov-20     23:44                ChildFolder
...
#>

Get-ChildItem -Recurse 
# Results all folder and file in root and sub-direcotries
<#
    Directory: D:\temp1


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                       
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                       
d-----         01-Nov-20     23:43                AddressFiles                                                                                               
d-----         01-Nov-20     23:43                BonoboGitServer                                                                                            
d-----         01-Nov-20     23:44                ChildFolder 
...
    Directory: D:\temp1\AddressFiles


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                       
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                       
-a----         06-Aug-16     18:25         406508 (MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.pdf                                                                  
-a----         19-Mar-20     19:57            156 File1.txt                                                                                                  
-a----         19-Mar-20     19:57            150 File2.txt 
...
#>

Get-ChildItem -Directory
# Results get only directory names
<#
    Directory: D:\temp1


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                       
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                       
d-----         01-Nov-20     23:43                AddressFiles                                                                                               
d-----         01-Nov-20     23:43                BonoboGitServer                                                                                            
d-----         01-Nov-20     23:44                ChildFolder
...
#>

Get-ChildItem -Directory | 
ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $PSItem.Name -Recurse | 
    Select-Object -Property Fullname
}
# Results use directory name to get all files in that directory tree
<#
FullName                                                                                                                     
--------                                                                                                                     
D:\temp1\AddressFiles\(MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.pdf                                                              
D:\temp1\AddressFiles\File1.txt                                                                                              
D:\temp1\AddressFiles\File2.txt
...
#>

Get-ChildItem -Directory | 
ForEach-Object {
    "`n *** Working on resource named: $($PSItem.BaseName) *** `n"
    ($DirName = $($PSItem.BaseName))
}
# Results
<#
 *** Working on resource named: AddressFiles *** 

AddressFiles

 *** Working on resource named: BonoboGitServer *** 

ChildFolder

 *** Working on resource named: dest *** 
...
#>

Get-ChildItem -Directory | 
ForEach-Object {
    "`n *** Working on resource named: $($PSItem.BaseName) *** `n"
    $DirName = $($PSItem.BaseName)

    Get-ChildItem -Path $DirName -File 
}
# Results
<#
 *** Working on resource named: AddressFiles *** 



    Directory: D:\temp1\AddressFiles


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                       
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                       
-a----         06-Aug-16     18:25         406508 (MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.pdf                                                                  
-a----         19-Mar-20     19:57            156 File1.txt                                                                                                  
-a----         19-Mar-20     19:57            150 File2.txt                                                                                                  

 *** Working on resource named: BonoboGitServer *** 


 *** Working on resource named: ChildFolder *** 



    Directory: D:\temp1\ChildFolder


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                       
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                       
-a----         29-Dec-19     21:50             69 5 Free Software You'll Wish You Knew Earlier! 2019 - YouTube.url                                           
-a----         10-Jan-20     17:59              0 awél.txt                                                                                                   
-a----         04-Jan-20     02:01             39 hello.bat 
#>

Get-ChildItem -Directory | 
ForEach-Object {
    "`n *** Working on resource named: $($PSItem.BaseName) *** `n"
    $DirName = $($PSItem.BaseName)

    Get-ChildItem -Path $DirName -File | 
    ForEach{
        $PSItem.FullName
    } 
}
# Results
<#
 *** Working on resource named: AddressFiles *** 

D:\temp1\AddressFiles\(MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.pdf
D:\temp1\AddressFiles\File1.txt
D:\temp1\AddressFiles\File2.txt

 *** Working on resource named: BonoboGitServer *** 


 *** Working on resource named: ChildFolder *** 

D:\temp1\ChildFolder\5 Free Software You'll Wish You Knew Earlier! 2019 - YouTube.url
D:\temp1\ChildFolder\awél.txt
D:\temp1\ChildFolder\hello.bat
...
#>
```

Comment: OK so by using this command I'm able to rename all the file in the sub-folders with the -recurse parameter :  

Get-ChildItem -Path .\folder1\ -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { "Prefix_" + $_.Name }

But how do I replace the "Prefix" with the sub-folder name ?

Comment: It's OK to be new to PowerShell, but, before using it to this level or even at all, it is vital you get/spend time training on it. Use Youtube PowerShell training to get up to speed.  Anyway, this is a straightforward process; using nested loops. Use an outer loop to get all the directory names (basename), then passed that to an implicit or explicit inner loop to get the files (FullName) in that folder and update with the FullName with the directory BaseName from the outer loop.